# Trouble simultaneously fetching filtered vertices and unfiltered vertices count

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I'm trying to return a *limited* number of vertices matching a pattern, as well as the total (*non-limited*) count of vertices matching that pattern.

```
g.V()
  .hasLabel("PersonPublic")
  .has('partitionKey', "Q2r1NaG6KWdScX4RaeZs")
  .has('docId', "Q2r1NaG6KWdScX4RaeZs")
  .out("CONTACT_LIST")
  .out("SUBSCRIBER")
  .dedup()
  .order()
    .by("identifier")
    .by("docId")
  .fold()
  .project('people','total')
    .by(
      unfold()
      .has('docId', gt("23")),
      .limit(2)
      .project('type','id')
        .by(label())
        .by(values('docId'))
    )
    .by(unfold().count())
```

In plain English, I'm finding a person, finding all the contact lists of that person, finding all the subscribers to those contact lists, de-duplicating the subscribers, ordering the subscribers, pausing there to collect everything and then projecting the results in the form

```
{
  people: [{type: string, id: string}],
  total: number,
}
```

- The "people" part of the projection is unfolded, filtered to only contain results with a "docId" greater than "23", limited to 2, and then projected again.
- The "total" part of the projection is unfolded (no-limit) and counted.

My goal is to allow paging through a pattern while still retrieving the total number of vertices associated with the pattern.

Unfortunately, on cosmosdb this query is not working. Results are in the form

```
{
  people: {type: string, id: string},
  total: number,
}
```

And only the first person result is returned (rather than an array).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `fold()` the projected value again, otherwise, it's always gonna be trimmed to the first one. Also, for the `total` you don't need to `unfold()`, that's just a waste of resources.

```
g.V()
  .hasLabel("PersonPublic")
  .has('partitionKey', "Q2r1NaG6KWdScX4RaeZs")
  .has('docId', "Q2r1NaG6KWdScX4RaeZs")
  .out("CONTACT_LIST")
  .out("SUBSCRIBER")
  .dedup()
  .order()
    .by("identifier")
    .by("docId")
  .fold()
  .project('people','total')
    .by(
      unfold()
      .has('docId', gt("23"))
      .limit(2)
      .project('type','id')
        .by(label)
        .by('docId')
      .fold()
    )
    .by(count(local))
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I spent an hour or two trying different query combinations searching for this! I find I still need to use `.by(unfold().count(local))` at the end though, otherwise `total: 1` always.